# differences between two sql statements

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and is doing some practice on sqlzoo (https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations). Per one of its questions, my SQL statement is judged as wrong, but I think it is equivalent to the reference statement.

There are three tables. Details can be found on [sqlzoo](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_details_about_the_database)

> This database features two entities (movies and actors) in a many-to-many relation. Each entity has its own table. A third table, casting , is used to link them. The relationship is many-to-many because each film features many actors and each actor has appeared in many films.

My statement

```
SELECT title, name
FROM casting JOIN movie ON movie.id=movieid
             JOIN actor ON actor.id=actorid
WHERE movieid in
(SELECT id FROM movie WHERE yr=1962)
AND ord=1
```

The reference statement that produces right result

```
SELECT title, name
FROM movie JOIN casting ON (id=movieid)
JOIN actor ON (actor.id = actorid)
WHERE ord=1 AND  yr = 1962
```

I cannot tell the difference between above two statements.

Comment: Your statement is logically equivalent.  But it is more complicated than necessary, using a subquery where a simple comparison would suffice.  (They are only the same because `id` is unique in `movie`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should both work and produce the same results. But the reference statement is much more efficient.

Comment: I think so. It's probably some error in sqlzoo's evaluation/judgement. Thank you.